# Cannot order posts by meta value

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to get a list of `Wordpress` posts, sorting them using the `meta_key` = "zoacres_property_price" in DESC order, so I did:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.* 
                      FROM wpps_posts p
                     CROSS
                      JOIN wpps_postmeta m
                     INNER
                      JOIN wpps_term_relationships r
                        ON p.ID = r.object_id
                     WHERE r.term_taxonomy_id IN (76) 
                       AND p.post_type = 'zoacres-property' 
                       AND p.post_status = 'publish'  
                       AND m.meta_key = 'zoacres_property_price'
                     GROUP 
                        BY p.ID 
                     ORDER 
                        BY m.meta_value ASC 
                    LIMIT 6, 6
```

unfortunately I got this error:

> Unknown column wpps_posts.ID in on clause

what I did wrong? The column exists

Comment: Note that in the absence og any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate, rendering everything that precedes it nonsensical.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the tip, I'll take care

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause!

I am guessing that you actually want to filter the posts by the conditions in the other two tables.  So, I suspect you want `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpps_posts.* 
FROM wpps_posts p JOIN
     wpps_term_relationships tr
     ON p.ID = tr.object_id AND tr.term_taxonomy_id IN ('76') JOIN
     wpps_postmeta pm
     ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'zoacres-property' AND
      p.post_status = 'publish' 
      pm.meta_key = 'zoacres_property_price'
ORDER BY pm.meta_value ASC
LIMIT 6, 6
```

Comment: Thank you su much